# Pass Parameter To Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pass some parameters to a stored procedure that is called via dynamic SQL like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someProc
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS
    DECLARE @qry varchar(max) = 'EXEC otherProc @StartDate, @EndDate'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
         @recipients = 'test@domain.com',    
         @subject = 'Test',
         @query = @qry,
         @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
         @query_attachment_filename = 'result.csv',
         @query_result_separator = '    ',
         @query_result_no_padding = 1,
         @query_result_width = 32767
```

But when I run this, I get an error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate"

How can I change my query to get this to work?

Comment: Format the dates in the `@qry` variable using `convert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it in literally? Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime='20170101';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime=GETDATE();


DECLARE @qry varchar(max) = 'EXEC otherProc {ts''' 
                           + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@StartDate,126),'T',' ')  
                           + '''}, {ts''' 
                           + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@EndDate,126),'T',' ')  + '''}';

SELECT @qry;
```

The result:

```
EXEC otherProc {ts'2017-01-01 00:00:00'}, {ts'2017-07-12 22:20:39'}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!!